# chickens, eggs and postgres in docker (Bootstrapping = no-can-do loop)

Tags: postgresql, docker

Instantiated and ran a postgres container:

going into it...

```
$ docker exec -it postgres su postgres
```

exeuting...

```
postgres@3eb98e824f39:/$ psql
```

response

```
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

can't `createuser` as it gives the same response. I thought PSQL comes out of the box with a `postgres` user. Otherwise -- how do you bootstrap?

on my `docker-compose.yaml` I have a volume mapping for my postgres container. But even zapping it, and letting it start from scratch when i `docker-up` doesn't work here.

How do I break the 'you cannot bootstrap because you cannot bootstrap' cycle?

Comment: it depends on the docker image you are using to run postgres

Comment: I used the "..:latest"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have suffered some kind of corruption. Removing the image and the container and starting them again resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should check how you run your Docker image

```
>docker run --name postgres -d postgres:latest
>docker exec -ti postgres su postgres
postgres@71bcfb3be14e:/$ psql
psql (11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.
```

Check the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) if you are running a specific version